# Search json with input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Im looking to set up a simple search input that checks a json file.

My current code is this, this does not work, because each json parent has a name.
if i remove the names "json1"/"json2" it works.

```js
var dataArr = [{
  "json1": {
      "car": "honda",
      "id": "0123",
      "name": "jim"
  },
  "json2": {
      "car": "toyota",
      "id": "0124",
      "name": "james"
  }
}];


$("#search").on('keypress keyup change input', function() {
    var arrival = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#matches').text(!arrival.length ? '' :
        dataArr.filter(function(place) {
            
            return (place.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(arrival) !== -1);
        }).map(function(place) {
            
            return place.name;
        }).join('\n'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>this does not work. because i have parent names for my json structure</b>
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search term">
<div id="matches" style="height:70px; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:pre"></div>
```

And here is an example of the code working, if i remove the "name" of parent json

```js
var dataArr = [{
      "car": "honda",
      "id": "0123",
      "name": "jim"
  },
{
      "car": "toyota",
      "id": "0124",
      "name": "james"
  }];


$("#search").on('keypress keyup change input', function() {
    var arrival = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#matches').text(!arrival.length ? '' :
        dataArr.filter(function(place) {
            return (place.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(arrival) !== -1);
        }).map(function(place) {
            return place.name;
        }).join('\n'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>this should work</b>
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search term">
<div id="matches" style="height:70px; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:pre"></div>
```

What could i do to make my top json example work?
as i have a huge json with multiple ID's set as the parent name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply convert first snippet array as like second snippet array . using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
var dataArr = [{ "json1": { "car": "honda", "id": "0123", "name": "jim" }, "json2": { "car": "toyota", "id": "0124", "name": "james" } }];

dataArr = Object.values(dataArr[0]);
$("#search").on('keypress keyup change input', function() {
  var arrival = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $('#matches').text(!arrival.length ? '' :
    dataArr.filter(function(place) {
      return (place.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(arrival) !== -1);
    }).map(function(place) {
      return place.name;
    }).join('\n'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>this does not work. because i have parent names for my json structure</b>
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search term">
<div id="matches" style="height:70px; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:pre"></div>
```

Comment: Absolute life saver!
Cant mark this as correct for 6 minutes, but i will do!

Comment: @Mic Welcome bro

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values`

```js
var dataArr = [{
  "json1": {
    "car": "honda",
    "id": "0123",
    "name": "jim"
  },
  "json2": {
    "car": "toyota",
    "id": "0124",
    "name": "james"
  }
}];


$("#search").on('keypress keyup change input', function() {
  var arrival = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  let filterVal = filteredVal(arrival);
  let car = filterVal[0] ? filterVal[0].car : ''
  $('#matches').text(!arrival.length ? '' : car);

})

function filteredVal(searchedName) {
  let getKeys = Object.values(dataArr[0]).filter(function(elem) {
    return elem.car == searchedName;
  });
  return getKeys;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search term">
<div id="matches" style="height:70px; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:pre"></div>
```